# Rust Environment Variables without dotenv

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I would like to load a set of Rust environment variables depending on my build environment (in my case, dev, uat and live). Ideally, I would like to specify the environment file ay build time.

Looking at online docs, the advice seems to be to use the `dotenv` crate. However, that crate is a v0 version, and does not appear to be maintained. Is there an idiomatic way to do this without using an old library?

Comment: There is [dotenvy](https://github.com/allan2/dotenvy), "A well-maintained fork of the Rust dotenv crate". Still in 0.x, though, but I'm not sure this is that bad.

Comment: Rust's dotenv crate was last updated 9 months ago. That's not particularly "old".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without external libraries you can use `cargo` [configuration](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#env) `env` property and have something like:

**Options A:** *Single configuration*

- `my-project/.cargo/config.toml`

```ini
[env]
MY_ENV="dev"
MY_DEV_HOST="localhost"
MY_PROD_HOST="prod.example.com"
```

- `my-project/src/main.rs`

```rust
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let my_env = env::var("MY_ENV")
        .unwrap_or("dev".to_string())
        .to_uppercase();
    let my_host = env::var(format!("MY_{}_HOST", my_env))?;

   // Do something
 
   Ok(())
}
```

then you run it with `cargo run` and it will take the default `dev` values, with `MY_ENV="prod" cargo run` will take prod values.

**Option B:** *Multiple configuration*

Another options if is a configuration per environment and use `--config` cargo command line option, for example:

- `my-project/stg-config.toml`

```ini
[env]
MY_ENV="stg"
MY_HOST="stg.example.com"
```

- `my-project/prod-config.toml`

```ini
[env]
MY_ENV="prod"
MY_HOST="prod.example.com"
```

and then `cargo run --config stg-config.toml`, if you have `.cargo/config.toml` (with default `env` values) it will merge those.